# Making text with variables for JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that makes a random number from 0 - 20. I wanted it to show up on screen so i did `document.write(variable)`. When i run it the whole page is blank except for the variable. How do you make the variable show up in the screen without having your page destroyed or something. Thank You!

Comment: This is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `document.write`.

Select a **DOMElement** and set it's **text** or **innerHTML** to your random generated number.

for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Example</title>
<div id="random"></div>
<script>
    var n = String(yourRandomGeneratedNumber);
    document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = n;
</script>
```

PS: the HTML is valid!

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped me a lot! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you use `document.write()` after your page is loaded, it will overwrite the HTML document. You can only use this command in the output stream.